# How do I ensure repeatability of Julia code and assoicated dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, julia, reproducible-research

Say I have a project where I am performing analysis (ie not looking to develop a sharable package) but I want to ensure that others could clone the repository and instantiate the dependencies and run the code as written.

Steps I have taken so far:

1. Created code in it's own folder
2. Made that folder a Julia environment (by `activate .` in the package mode of the REPL)
3. `add`ed the packages I am using

Does this lock in the versions of the dependencies? Or do I need to manually add `[compat]` entries to the `Project.toml` file? If the `[compat]` entreis are necessary, is there a way to auto-include that entry when `add`ing the package?

Is there a overall approach to ensuring reporducability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this lock in the versions of the dependencies?

If you commit your `Project.toml` and `Manifest.toml` then someone can clone the repo, activate that project and do `import Pkg; Pkg.instantiate()` to download the exact same versions as are recorded in the manifest.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this lock in the versions of the dependencies?

Yes, in the sense that the exact versions are recorded in the `Manifest.toml` file so as long as that file is not modified they are locked.

> Or do I need to manually add `[compat]` entries to the `Project.toml` file?

You don't have to do this. This only matters when someone performs a package operation that invokes the resolver, for example `pkg> add ...` or `pkg> up`. If your code relies on some specific version of a package you can always add this to the `[compat]` section. For example, if you rely on a feature that requires package `X` version 1.3.0 you can add

```
[compat]
X = "1.3"
```

This will ensure that, even if someone invokes the package resolver, you will *at least* get version 1.3 of package `X`.